# SQL execute SP using parameters from table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a stored procedute which I can execute like :

```
exec Clientinvoicing_BackUPReports @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID = 9, @Outletid = 208,  @ReportStartdate =  '2015-23-01', @ReportEnddate = '2015-19-02'
```

I would like to be able to use the parameters from my table. my table has the below fields

```
Rownumber, HeadofficeclientinvoiceID,  Outletid, ReportStartdate, ReportEnddate
```

also I would like to run the stored procedure for each row in the table. there are 20 records in the table (rownumber 20)

Comment: in this case you'll have to use a [Cursor](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/)

Comment: provide what you have tried yet..

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag appropriately: Oracle, SQL Server, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write functions which call stored procedures. So you need to define a function which gets table value parameters and executes the stored procedure. Evaluate the function inside the query.

Example function:

```
FUNCTION total_comp
   (salary_in IN employee.salary%TYPE, bonus_in IN employee.bonus%TYPE)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
   RETURN salary_in + NVL (bonus_in, 0);
END;
```

Example usage:

```
SELECT employee_name, total_comp (salary, bonus)
  FROM employee;
```

[Source](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch17_01.htm).

You can do this by iterating the table rows using a [cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) as well.

Comment: is there an alternative way. I been told using a sql as a string may be an option.

Comment: @Abbaskhan, you can do that, but it would be too hacky. I have shown you two different solutions.